# Having an image at the bottom of the page at all time in HTML

Tags: html, image, footer

I'm working on a basic html webpage and I'm still learing it that's the reason for this stupid question.

So basically I have this image which is a bar that I want to have going at the bottom of the page and staying at that location even if you scroll on the page. So basically it will always be visable. You can call it a footer I guess but it should always be visable.

Hope you understand what I mean.

How do I do this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in your CSS something like this:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    /* eventually */
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

That should do the trick - apply it to a DIV element and put your image inside or set it as a background.

Comment: Aright thanks, but how do I call for this function in my <footer>

Comment: Add it in your CSS file, but if you have it as `<footer>Content</footer>`, remove the hashtag from `#footer`. If you can't find the file, wrap the above code with `<style type="text/css"> -code here- </style>` and put it in your `header` (right before `</head>` tag)

Comment: Okay just one last question, and sorry for the stupidity of it.
How do I make it so it functions my image footer.jpg?

Comment: `<img src="footer.jpg" id="footer" />`, but then please change in the code from `#footer` to `img#footer` to avoid possible collissions with other elements.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appriciate it!